# SQL GROUP BY Issue on GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I've written a  query that builds a small table of information from a couple of data sources, it uses a self made table to reference the vehicle model for the final group by which is how the data needs to be viewed, however when I group by vehicle it misses out figures in the subquery column from the group by, i.e. if I group by Prefix it shows the correct numbers, grouped by Vehicle hides off some of the data.

The Prefix can relate to a couple of like vehicle models and hence the need to group by vehicle. Can anyone see what I've done wrong easily from the SQL query below please.

```
SELECT Vehicle, COUNT(`Chassis-No`) AS Stock, 
ROUND((100/COUNT(`Chassis-No`)) * SUM(CASE WHEN `Vehicle Age` > '182' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),1) AS Perc6Months, 
ROUND((100/COUNT(`Chassis-No`)) * SUM(CASE WHEN `Vehicle Age` > '365' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),1) AS Perc12Months,
(SELECT COUNT(VIN_Prefix) FROM Orderdownload 
    INNER JOIN VehicleMatrix ON (`VIN_Prefix` LIKE 'S%' AND Prefix = LEFT(`VIN_Prefix`,2)) OR (`VIN_Prefix` NOT LIKE 'S%' AND Prefix = LEFT(`VIN_Prefix`,1)) WHERE DealerCode = 'AA12345' AND `VIN_Prefix` = IF(LEFT(`Chassis-No`,1)='S',LEFT(`Chassis-No`,2),LEFT(`Chassis-No`,1))) As Qty
FROM DealerAgedStock
    INNER JOIN VehicleMatrix AS VM
      ON (`Chassis-No` LIKE 'S%' AND Prefix = LEFT(`Chassis-No`,2)) OR (`Chassis-No` NOT LIKE 'S%' AND Prefix = LEFT(`Chassis-No`,1))    
WHERE `DL Dealer Code` = 'AA12345'
GROUP BY Vehicle
```

Grouped on Vehicle I get the following:

```
Vehicle | Perc6Months | Perc12Months | Qty
Mondeo | 37.5 | 0 | 2
```

Grouped on Prefix I get the following:

```
VIN_Prefix | Perc6Months | Perc12Months | Qty
S1 | 25 | 0 | 2
S2 | 50 | 0 | 2
```

**Ideally it should look this this:**

```
Vehicle | Perc6Months | Perc12Months | Qty
Mondeo | 37.5 | 0 | 4
```

Where S1 and S2 are relative to the Vehicle Mondeo, thus it gives me the first instance of subquery rather than adding them together.

**My question is:** why does the Group By not add the figures together properly from the subquery? I need it to add them to have the correct figures...

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Can you add titles to your table please

Comment: Also, you appear not to be showing the query you are using: the comumn names in the select don't match those in the expected results. This makes it difficult to know what you are actually running: can you edit and correct the question?

Comment: Point taken, corrected now to reflect query.